# R + Multilevel Logistic Regression + Group Fixed Effects

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multilevel-analysis

In Stata, I know that if I use the following command, I can get the logits for each possible combination between my dependent variable (`thkbins`) and my two predictor variables (`cc` & `tv`):

```
melogit thkbins cc#tv || school:,
```

[image]

Is there a way to produce a similar output in R?  I have been using the `glmer` command from the `lme4` package, and while I can get the output with the interaction term, it isn't exactly what I can produce in Stata.

```
model1 <- glmer(thkbin ~ cc + tv + cc*tv + (1|school),
            data=thkdata, family = binomial, nAGQ = 7)
summary(model1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use `clmm` from the package `ordinal` (tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clmm2_tutorial.pdf)):

```
model<-clmm(DepVar~IndVar+(1|WithinVar),data=df)
```

I hope this helps.